# How to hide alertDialog after one second with Navigator.of(context).pop()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to auto-hide an alertDialog after one second

This is the code:

```
Widget popupWidget(BuildContext context, ...) {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  });
  return AlertDialog(...);}
```

What works:

- I can click somewhere else on the screen to close the alertDialog
- I can wait for one second and it closes automatically

The bug:

If, after (exactly?) one second, I click somewhere else on the screen (which closes the alertDialog), the Future.delayed(...) will not hide the alertDialog, but the whole screen

I unsuccessfully tried making `showDialog` async, also tried the line

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround with:

```
bool popupIsActive = true;

Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
if (popupIsActive) Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```

and

```
showDialog(...).then((_) {
popupIsActive = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ignore any taps outside the dialog in order to prevent it from dismissing and just wait for the future to complete. You can set `barrierDismissible` to false in `showDialog()`.